What the difference between wrapping a NavigationLink with a ForEach and using .navigationDestination
I was following a SWIFTUI tutorial and for one of the challenges me and the instructor created the same functionality but out code differed
his approach:
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List(users) { user in
            NavigationLink(value: user) {
            HStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(user.isActive ? .green : .red)
                    .frame(width: 30)
                
                Text(user.name)
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Friendface")
    .navigationDestination(for: User.self) { user in
        DetailView(user:user)
    }
    .task {
        await loadData()
    }

and my approach:
    NavigationStack{
        List {
            ForEach(users) { user in
                
                NavigationLink{
                    DetailView(user:user)
                label: {
                    HStack {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(user.isActive ? .green : .red)
                            .frame(width: 30)
                        
                        Text(user.name)
                    }
                }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .task {
            await loadData()
        }
    }

whats the difference between the two approaches in terms of readability and scalability?

Old vs new, his approach is new and much more versatile.

Why is it more versatile

Because it works with NavigationStack’s path which can be incredibly helpful when designing more complex navigation experiences. But it is more scalable because you can customize the navigation per type in one spot.

@loremipsum If you're answering the question, please write it in an answer, not a comment.

@JeremyP sure when/if I decide to answer. An answer to me merits more than a one line comment. I actually like elaborating for answers. I would be more inclined to answer if SO didn’t block my answers saying they are AI generated.

@loremipsum the problem is that the question doesn't look like it's got an answer when it actually has, but in a comment. Answers don't have to be long, they just have to be right.

@JeremyP someone else looking for points will elaborate on my comments and answer. SO has blocked my original answers more times than I can count. Idk what it is about the way I answer but it just isn’t worth it most of the time.

The difference is that when you don't use .navigationDestination whatever is inside the navigationLink will get created as soon as the app starts, which is fine when you aren't iterating through a large list but if your navigationLink is in a large List you have to use .navigationDestination if you do not want the views to be created automatically
